# Scrolling issue with plain HTML and overflow:auto in native Android browser

Tags: android, html, css, scroll

A simple HTML page contains a div with overflow-y:auto inside of another  div with overflow-y:auto. This page scrolls normally on touch devices with IOS Safari and Android Chrome browsers.

However, if I open the same page in a native Android v.4.0 to 4.3 browser and scroll the outer div, the inner div does not move synchronously with the remaining content and jumps to its place only after some delay.

The same happens if the internal div has overflow-x: auto.

Example page: http://jsbin.com/cojoluwo/1/

The code looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #content {
            height: 100%;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
        #scroller{
            height: 100px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            width: 200px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body class='sapUiBody'>
    <div id='content'>
        <div>
            <p> some text 
                    ......
            <p> some text 
            <div id=scroller>
                <p>internal text
                            ...........
                <p>internal text
            </div>
            <p> some text 
                    ...........
            <p> some text 
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it a bug? If yes, is there any workaround known?

Comment: I'm having this same issue, the first div tracks along synchronously with a finger, where the rest trail........ looks really bad. I'm checking now if a "document" element is necessary between the "viewport" and the "child divs"

Comment: ok it seems to work in generic, mobile web (Chrome) and our SDK just had an older version embedded for web views

Answer (score 1):

there's no need for this:

```
#content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

a scrollable div with a set `overflow` inside another scrollable div with a set `overflow` is not a good idea on mobile and since your css properties for `#content` are redundant and not useful, you can safely remove them and it will work

http://jsbin.com/cojoluwo/5

Comment: The code sample above just demonstrates the issue. In my particular case, I need a horizontally scrollable area like horizontal thumbnail scroller inside of a vertically scrollable area. Why is it not a good idea on mobile? Doesn't it conform to CSS specification? Mobile Chrome browser and mobile Safari browser both process it correctly.

Comment: is this your real code? just noticed you have a thousand <p> tags that never close, and that certainly may break things

Comment: No, it is just quick and dirty example. However, the code shows the issue. My real code has several thousands lines.

Comment: <p> tag does not need to be closed in HTML5. it breaks nothing. see here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html

Comment: sorry i've been testing several things in the meantime but nothing seem to work